# Float formatting JSON Dump with Python and Google App Engine Issue

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine, webapp2

I am currently working with python and creating a simple API on Google App Engine that allows a user to use the GET, POST, DELETE, and PUT verbs by making API calls using the command line. I am using curl to manipulate the data with the API calls. I have been able to successfully add data and display it back but the problem is I have an attribute for 'price' and this price is stored in the datastore on GAE (Google App Engine) as a float and the number is formatted as it is submitted but when the JSON shows whats in the datastore it has a different format. For example storing price 8.99 the JSON response shows 8.9900000000000002. I am pretty sure this is not a GAE problem but a JSON problem.

Example of problem:

```
curl --data "name=t-shirt&description=Star Trek&price=8.99&user=test1" -H "Accept: application/json" https://mywebsite.appspot.com/product
```

Stores in datastore correctly but returns JSON like this:

```
{"description": "Star Trek", "price": 8.9900000000000002, "name": "t-shirt", "user": "test1", "key": 5206065687822336}
```

Here are my models.py

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class Model(ndb.Model):
    def to_dict(self):
        d = super(Model, self).to_dict()
        d['key'] = self.key.id()
        return d

class User(Model):
    username = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    password = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)

class Product(Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    description = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    price = ndb.FloatProperty()
    color = ndb.StringProperty()
    size = ndb.StringProperty()
    user = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)

class Sales(Model):
    products = ndb.KeyProperty(repeated=True)
    datetime = ndb.DateTimeProperty(required=True)
    quantity = ndb.IntegerProperty(repeated=True)
    product_cost = ndb.FloatProperty(repeated=True)
    total_cost = ndb.FloatProperty()
    latitude = ndb.FloatProperty()
    longitude = ndb.FloatProperty()
    user = ndb.KeyProperty(required=True)


    def to_dict(self):
        d = super(Sales, self).to_dict()
        d['products'] = [i.id() for i in d['products']]
        return d
```

Here is product.py:

```
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
import models
import json

class Product(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    #Create a Product entity
    def post(self):
        if 'application/json' not in self.request.accept:
            self.response.status = 406
            self.response.status_message = 'Not acceptable, API only supports application/json MIME type.'
            return
        new_product = models.Product()
        name = self.request.get('name', default_value=None)
        description = self.request.get('description', default_value=None)
        price = self.request.get('price', default_value=0)
        color = self.request.get('color', default_value=None)
        size = self.request.get('size', default_value=None)
        user = self.request.get('user', default_value=None)

        if name:
            new_product.name = name
        else:
            self.response.status = 400
            self.response.status_message = 'Invalid request, name required'
        if description:
            new_product.description = description
        else:
            self.response.status = 400
            self.response.status_message = 'Invalid request, description required'
        if price:
            new_product.price = float(price)
        if color:
            new_product.color = color
        if size:
            new_product.size = size
        if user:
            new_product.user = user
        else:
            self.response.status = 400
            self.response.status_message = 'Invalid request, username required'
        key = new_product.put()
        out = new_product.to_dict()
        self.response.write(json.dumps(out))
        return

    #Return an Product entity
    def get(self, **kwargs):
        if 'application/json' not in self.request.accept:
            self.response.status = 406
            self.response.status_message = 'Not acceptable, API only supports application/json MIME type.'
            self.response.write(self.response.status_message)
            return
        #Return selected product details
        if 'id' in kwargs:
            out = ndb.Key(models.Product, int(kwargs['id'])).get().to_dict()
            self.response.write(json.dumps(out))
        #Return all product ids
        else:
            q = models.Product.query()
            keys = q.fetch(keys_only=False)
            results = {x.key.id() : x.to_dict() for x in keys}
            self.response.write(json.dumps(results))
```

I apologize for the overkill but I wanted to make sure everything was available to see. Any help would be much appreciated. I have looked at some similar items but the way I am using a dictionary here I can't seem to get this format correct.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's actually an issue. If you want to understand why there is this disrepancy you might want to read the Wikipedia article on [floating point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point). The TLDR is that there are already infinitely many rational numbers between 0 and 1 but the computer is only able to store a finite amount of data. More so you usually want to store real numbers within 32 (single) or 64 (double) bits of data to allow for efficient computation. Machine numbers therefore are only a subset of the real numbers and you often have to round to the closest machine number. This wouldn't be an issue if the dot was always at the same place and you were using base 10 numbers so you would know there is no error in rounding "8.99" but this is not the case with normal floating point numbers as defined in IEEE 754.

Basically 8.99 = 8.9900000000000002 holds here.

You have several options how to fix the issue:

### 1) Don't fix the issue and just round the values on display

**Warning**: This is likely not what you want.
Usually it is ok to just round off the error on displaying since usually the error is very tiny, for examples in a game this would likely be acceptable. However in this case you seem to be creating a shop and it might be problematic if there are different roundings at different places. For example it might create a difference of 0.01 on an order under certain circumstances which could lead to various kinds of issues. Don't store prices/amounts of money in floating point numbers.

### 2) Use integer values [probably the best option here]

Instead of storing 8.99 you store 899 as an integer number in the database. Integer arithmetics doesn't have round off issues if you use only addition/subtraction.

This is probably a bit inconvenient since it will involve updating the database and the displaying of numbers (i.e. you will have to insert a dot at the right location). But it is likely the safest bet you have and what is generally considered a good option if you don't have access to specialized numbers.

### 3) Use fixed point numbers with the right basis

If you do a lot of arithmetics with such numbers it might be more convenient to use a fixed point number library and basically use a tailor made rational number representation for your problem. It is basically the same as option 2 but you don't implement everything yourself and have more flexibility. However I personally would go with option 2 as I don't know if there is such a library that you could use in both Python and Javascript and also it might just involve an unescessary dependency to the project.